# Autocomplete en DataGridView - Windows Form c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview, textbox, autocomplete

Tengo un problema que no logro resolver. Estoy creando una pantalla en la que se carga una lista de textos, digamos "nombre de productos", en una celda del DataGridView. La idea es que al escribir en dicha celda, el sistema me autocomplete el nombre del producto de acuerdo a lo que escribo y, al seleccionar el producto, me carga en las demás columnas los datos asociados al mismo. Hasta ahora no tengo problema con lo antes mencionado, mi problema es que el autocompletado funciona tal como en un TextBox mediante la lógica del "empieza con..." y lo que necesito es que se aplique una búsqueda mediante la lógica del "contiene".

Código:

Declaro la siguiente coleccion para guardar el nombre de los productos

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection ProductCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

private void LoadProducts()
        {
            ProductList = productBL.GetProductsQuote();

            foreach(var item in ProductList)
            {
                ProductCollection.Add(item.ProductNameES);
            }
        }
```

En el evento EditingControlShowing del DataGridView añado esta lógica

```
string titleText = dgv1.Columns[dgv1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name;
    
    if (titleText.Equals("Product"))
    {
       TextBox autoText = e.Control as TextBox;
        
       if (autoText != null)
       {
           autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
           autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
           autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ProductCollection;
       }
    }
```

De esta manera, logro hacer lo antes mencionado sin problema. Mi dolor de cabeza es que no logro hallar la manera de que haga la búsqueda de lo que escribo entre todo lo que coincida sea al inicio, al medio o al final.

Intenté implementar algo como lo detallado en el siguiente link con una clase custom. Me funciona perfectamente en los textbox del formulario, pero no logro aplicarlo al DataGridView

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437002/winforms-c-sharp-autocomplete-in-the-middle-of-a-textbox

Si alguien tiene una solución, lo agradezco mucho!

Comment: Está complejo el asunto. Francamente creo que no vale la pena, yo me quedaría con el autocomplete normal

Comment: Igual que comentas que lo hiciste con TextBox custom, deberás crear un DataGridView custom para aplicar esta regla y modificar el autocompletado para que coja los valores que empiecen, contengan o terminen por lo que escribas. O usar los eventos de Keydown o keypress para ir controlando esos cambios y sugerir el texto que desees.